# Excel countif getting error or NA when another workbook is closed

Tags: excel, count, formula

I am trying to use countifs for multiple criteria from another workbook but when I closed the another workbook , the formula show #NA , understand that countifs not work with closed workbook , any formula work great with closed workbook and able to count ?

Comment: `AGGREGATE` works on closed workbooks.  Maybe you can rewrite your formula to use that

Comment: For example my countifs formula is this > countifs(another wbook,a2, another wbook,c2)  so if I am using aggregate how the formul should look like ?

Comment: Been trying aggregate but unable to find result